# How to check for multiple possible values of a string in Java

Tags: java, boolean

I want to perform the same operation for more than one value of a string called `contents`

```
if (contents == "chicken roll" , contents == toasted chicken){
      // do some common operation
    }
```

What is the proper Java syntax for this?

Comment: what you wrote has no sense at all... do you mean "if contents is 'chicken roll' or contents is 'toasted chicken'" ? or do you mean "if contents is 'chicken roll' and contents is 'toasted chicken'" ? and by the way, do you consider "contents" being something like a collection of "things related to chicken" or contents is one chicken (i.e. "if 'chicken roll' is in contents or 'toasted chicken' is in contents")?

Comment: See [boolean operators](http://www.freejavaguide.com/boolean_operators.htm)

Comment: @zmo: Since the title is "if something = something or something", I guess he means "or".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a logical or `||`:

```
if (contents.equals("chicken roll") || contents.equals("toasted chicken")){
```

See the [list of operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Also note that you compare for string equality using the `equals` method.